# Ping not answered to hyper-v vw machine and not remote desktop

Tags: hyper-v, sharepoint, rdp, ping

I got three vhdx files. One for SQL-server, one for AD and the other one is SharePoint. Inside Hypver-v manager, I created three Virutal Machines for those three vhdx files and chose same Internal Virtual Switch. I can browse to Internet inside all these three VMs. I can connect to the AD and SharePoint virtual machine using RDP but not the sql server. And none of the SharePoint sites working becuase SharePoint cannot find the sql server.

When I compare the settings of these three VMs inside the hypver-v manager, all three have same settings. According to my colleage everything worked on his machine.

Why neither ping nor RDP work on the sql server and why the SharePoint server cannot find the sql server?

Comment: An `Internal Virtual Switch`? Are you sure? An Internal Virtual Switch allows for communication between VM's and between VM's and the host, but not the physical network beyond the host.

Answer (score 1):

check firewall in guest, disable it if you could just for test.

Comment: No it is possible to reach the server using RDP. But still having problem with SharePoint sites and it cannot communicate with sql server

Comment: check what port is required for communicating with those servers - different services require different ports - and verify ports are open between them using tools such as portqry

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the default gateway on the servers, then double check the firewall on the SQL server. When you enable RDP on a server, it can add a rule to the firewall which would explain why that is working and not Ping/ICMP.

Can you ping the other two servers from the SQL server?

Comment: Yes I can ping the other two servers. After I disabled firewall I can access the sql server using RDP. But still the SharePoint cannot find the sql server and generates this error: This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm

Answer (score 0):

I removed the sql server from the domain server and readded it again now everything is working.